# The :enabled selector in Microsoft Edge

Tags: jquery, microsoft-edge

When using the selector :enabled, Microsoft Edge includes link-tags in the head-section.
Run the code snippet in Chrome/Firefox/IE and then ME and compare the result.
Is this a known bug?

```js
$(":enabled").each(function () {
  alert(this.tagName);
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>enabled demo</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://api.jquery.com/jquery-wp-content/themes/api.jquery.com/i/favicon.ico">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <input id="input1" disabled="disabled">
    <input id="input2">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Interesting, I tried to add disabled to the link tag and it didn't alert it anymore. But I have no idea if that can cause some other problem.

Comment: It can cause a problem if one tries to manipulate the elements found with $(":enabled"). That's how I found the bug.

Comment: Can't imagine you would ever use that selector by itself anyway

Comment: Every browser executes the code differently. If you replace the Link with any other HTML element than it will display its name if it is not disabled. But you also did not explicitly mentioned in the code that it is disabled or not. I suggest you to adjust your code properly and than try to make a test.

Comment: The bug is actually in other browsers. The link elements should be collected with the said selector, since link element can be disabled/enabled.

Comment: Thanks Teemu, the disabled attribute on links is not a standard attribute, but I guess you are right; might be the other browsers doing it wrong. Should I change the title on the question post?